# Style is not being applied to the recent google material button dependency

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-styles, material-components-android

Recently I updated to Android Studio 4.0 and updated all the Gradle dependencies. Styles are being properly applied for

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

but for `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'` styles aren't being applied to the material buttons.

Sample Code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/Button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sampleButton"
                style="@style/SelectionButtonStyle" />
```

for style:

```
<style name="SelectionButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_24sdp</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/selection_button_background</item>
    </style>
```

for the button background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="#9C27B0" />

    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:color="#1A237E" />

    <corners
        android:radius="@dimen/_10sdp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Why you don't just use a stable version?

Comment: I am using the stable one. Just curious if someone else is using the recent one and has a work around. Or maybe a google engineer may make a note :)

Comment: What kind of colour do you want to set in your button? I'm using your style and it is working fine.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 3):

Only starting with [`1.2.0-alpha06`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/309d71860f0686137277915fb09e7502cbafc2b4) you can use the **`android:background`** attribute in the `MaterialButton`.

Since you are using the `android:background` in your layout the versions `1.1.0` and `1.3.0-alpha01` have a different behaivior.

In your case, you are trying to apply a stroke and a corner radius, and you can achieve the same behaivior simply using the default attributes:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   style="@style/SelectionButtonStyle"
   .../>
```

with:

```
<style name="SelectionButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">#9C27B0</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">10dp</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">#1A237E</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">4dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

add this to your view `app:backgroundTint="@null"`

Comment: won't that just remove the background color of the button?

Comment: no, in new material button background color set is not work until you add this to your view